# 'default' option in pgp.as.format()

Tags: javascript, pg-promise

I need to format SQL query with `default` option for missing object fields. I can do it with an external call to pgp.as.format:

```
let formattedQuery = pgp.as.format('INSERT INTO some_table (a,b,c) VALUES ($(a), $(b), $(c))', object, {default: null}); 
db.none(formattedQuery);
```

Is it possible to pass `default` option directly without pre-formatting the query? Basically, i would like to do something like this:

```
db.none('INSERT INTO some_table (a,b,c) VALUES ($(a), $(b), $(c))', object, {default: null})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the author of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise).

---

All query methods in [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) rely on the default query formatting, for better reliability, i.e. when a query template refers to a property, the property must exist, or else an error is thrown. It is logical to keep it that way, because a query cannot execute correctly while having properties in it that haven't been replaced with values.

Internally, the query engine does support advanced query formatting options, via method [as.format](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/formatting.html#.format), such as `partial` and `default`. And there are several objects in the library that make use of those options.

One in particular that you should use for generating inserts is [helpers.insert](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.insert), which can generate both single-insert and multi-insert queries. That method, along with even more useful [helpers.update](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.update) make use of type [ColumnSet](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html), which is highly configurable, supporting default values for missing properties (among other things), via type [Column](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.Column.html).

Using [ColumnSet](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html), you can specify a default value either for selective columns or for all of them.

For example, let's assume that column `c` may be missing, in which case we want to set it to `null`:

```
var pgp = require('pg-promise')({
    capSQL: true // to capitalize all generated SQL
});

// declaring a reusable ColumnSet object:
var csInsert = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(['a', 'b',
    {
        name: 'c',
        def: null
    }
], {table: 'some_table'});

var data = {a:1, b:'text'};

// generating our insert query:
var insert = pgp.helpers.insert(data, csInsert);
//=> INSERT INTO "some_table"("a","b","c") VALUES(1,'text',null)
```

This makes it possible to generate multi-insert queries automatically:

```
var data = [{a:1, b:'text'}, {a:2, b:'hello'}];

// generating a multi-insert query:
var insert = pgp.helpers.insert(data, csInsert);
//=> INSERT INTO "some_table"("a","b","c") VALUES(1,'text',null),(2,'hello',null)
```

The same approach works nicely for single-update and multi-update queries.

In all, to your original question:

> Is it possible to pass default option directly without pre-formatting the query?

No, and neither it should. Instead, you should use the aforementioned methods within the [helpers](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html) namespace to generate correct queries. They are way more powerful and flexible ;)

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer!